# Need to force #default_value for AJAX tableselect checkboxes

Tags: forms, ajax, theming

I built a drop-down ajax pager that replaces a tableselect with the requested page of rows. The array of selected item IDs is stored in a hidden field and that logic is working across entity load/save and AJAX replacements.

When the form initially loads, my tableselect #default_value operates correctly and checks the selected rows on the first page. But after AJAX paging through the big list to a different page and back, the checkboxes aren't checked again.

I think this has to do with #default_value only working before the form has been submitted. How can I reset the state so that my updated tableselect #default_value is used after AJAX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just before the tableselect's array in the form builder function, put the following code:

```
unset($form_state['input']['my_tableselect']);
```

Comment: Wow dude I checked your solution. And it's the only one which is working. I just looked into this discussion (https://www.drupal.org/node/1458824) that this is actually a core bug. But your line and all is working fine. Great man. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Btw for me it was `unset($form_state['input']['table']);` because my table is called in another way. And I called it in the custom `submit` callback at the very begin.

Answer (score 0):

For those ones experiencing the same case in Drupal 8, this is the equivalent solution:

```
$user_input = $form_state->getUserInput();
unset($user_input['my_tableselect']);
$form_state->setUserInput($user_input);
```